# Get the major diagonal and sub diagonal for matrix

Tags: java, arrays

Am confused about getting the  "sub diagonal" for 2D array, I can get the columns , rows and major diagonal, but i don't know how to get sub diagonal, here is what i'v done so far:

```
int size = input.nextInt();
int[][] list = initiateArr(size);
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i  ; j < i + 1; j++) {
            System.out.print(list[i][j] + " ");
        }
    }
```

My attempt for "sub diagonal":

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        for (int j = (list.length / 2) + 1; j > list.length - (i + 1) ; j--) {
            System.out.print(list[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.println("j = " + j);
        }
    }
```

How to get sub diagonal?

[image]

I can get the major diagonal right as described in the output `1111`, the sub diagonal should be `1010`.

Comment: Define major and sub diagonal?

Comment: @user3437460 i updated question

Comment: @android Does my answer help you or subdiagnal?

Comment: @android to avoid confusion I deleted my old answer and added new one. Check if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

 int[][] list = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
 int matrixSize = 3;

 System.out.println("Subdiagonal");
 for( int i = 0; i < matrixSize ; i ++){
   System.out.print( list[i][matrixSize - i -1] + " ");
 }
 System.out.println("");
 System.out.println("Major ");
 for( int i = 0; i < matrixSize ; i ++){
   System.out.print( list[i][i] + " ");
 }

}
```

Comment: What part of code didn’t u like ? Accordingly I can optimize.

Comment: as i said, for example your code doesn't support custom cases, assume i have 5*5 matrix and i need 3 major and this 3 start from 2nd row and 2nd column, your code doesn't cover that.